# Virtual Machine In Browser

Tags: vmware

I am using a virtual machine with a title "VNC" through a browser: I can login to a cloud-based operating system running on Linux.

When I open up firefox and go to google.com on the browser-based virtual machine, can it be tracked externally on the host browser (the host browser would have the same address all the time)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/servers configurations, applications, application-layer protocols, networks you do not directly control, and bypassing network security or policies are all off-topic here. You should assume that the network administrators can see anything you do on their network.